# Optimizar función que compruebe contenido de una cadena

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo que realizar una función, que pasado un texto por parámetro, me devuelva True si antes de un punto (.) o una coma (,) hay un espacio en blanco. Pensé en convertir el texto a una lista con split, pero para mantener el string ¿hay otra forma?

```
def mostrar(texto):
    if ("." in texto or "," in texto):
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: Creo que en este caso no va a importar mucho, pero sería bueno añadir la versión de Python que estás usando.

Comment: Estoy usando la versión 3.8..

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar expresiones regulares para lo que quieres con el siguiente patron:

```
(?<=[ ])[.,]
```

La expresión tiene dos partes:

1. `(?<=[ ])`

   Si encuentras un espacio verifique la siguiente expresión.
2. `[.,]`

   Si hay un . o  ,  entonces, es válido

El código es el siguiente:

```py
import re

def mostrar(texto):
    return  re.search(r"(?<=[ ])[.,]", texto) != None
```

**EDICION:** Habia puesto al revés la expresión.

Comment: Muy bueno, pero estoy buscando hacerlo sin expresiones regulares.

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que buscas es la secuencia: ESPACIO + punto, o ESPACIO + coma, simplemente hay que hacer una pequeña modificación (añadir el espacio antes de la cadena punto y otro antes de la cadena coma):

```
def mostrar(texto):
    if (' .' in texto or ' ,' in texto):
        return True
    return False
```

Si no te he entendido bien, por favor aclara un poco más tu pregunta. Gracias

Comment: Si agregas una explicación de lo que modificaste ayudaría a hacer más entendible tu aporte

Comment: y si el parametro es asi (texto=",34")

Comment: "y si el parametro es asi (texto=",34") "   En ese caso la función anterior dará false. Necesitas que de True en ese caso?

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente podrías utilizar algo así:

```
def mostrar(texto):
    return " ," in texto or " ." in texto
```

y así estarías devolviendo TRUE o FALSE dependiendo del texto que le ingreses